# Structure of lisp projects

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, allegro, maxima

When I use Eclipse or Visual Studio or Xcode, structure of the project gets created automatically and one can get started immediately.

Now I am trying to create a project on Allegro CL express edition and if I collect all lisp files and run it, it shows package errors which I believe is because of files not getting executed in a specific order as packages must be created in some file that must be executed first.

I am not able to understand how to approach this problem. There is no or little information on creating large projects in lisp and how to incrementally deal with its size and complexity.

I want to port [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) onto Allegro CL. Can I get some help here and also if one can explain this break up of code in multiple files and packages and basically how to load the whole system.

I know basics of lisp but I don't understand lisp project's structure.

Comment: I found very useful [Quickproject](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html), a tool that introduces you gently to the complexities of the Common Lisp standard way of building systems, [ASDF](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/).

Comment: @Renzo : I am aware of it but how to use it. I think it is apt for small projects only.

Comment: Ok, so the obvious advice then is to read the ASDF [documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/#documentation), but I think it could be useful download some complex project from [Quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org) and look to the way it is built. There are lot of projects that can be taken as example. Another interesting reading is the paper on [the last version of the system] (http://fare.tunes.org/files/asdf3/asdf3-2014.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good news: Maxima already has an Allegro port. You should be able to build it using `./configure --with-acl` then type `make`. I haven't used this recently, but I would expect this to work.

If you want to know more about how stuff is loaded, look at `src/maxima.system`. It's a bit archaic because it is written for `defsystem`, which has now been replaced pretty much everywhere else by `asdf`.

Comment: Acl IDE runs out of heap size. It gets built with acl but doesn't automatically get converted as project.

Answer (score 6):

Well, Maxima can be compiled via defsystem or asdf  by several Lisps, including Allegro. See INSTALL.lisp for details.

The only limitation that I know of is that the Allegro Express version cannot compile the SLATEC-derived code (the functions translated from Fortran are too big or something like that). So you will have to comment out the SLATEC stuff in maxima.system or maxima.asd.